# PyTorch set device using transfromers accelerator

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use deberta-v3 for a regression task and I am using the gradient accumulation steps trick to fit the model in the GPU memory. I have multiple GPUs, so I want to set the accelerator GPU to one with more free memory.

This is the snippet of the code I am using

```
from accelerate import Accelerator
accelerator = Accelerator(gradient_accumulation_steps=config['gradient_accumulation_steps'])
device = get_least_utilized_gpu()
print("utilized device:", device) # it correctly prints 'cuda:3'

# before was .to(device=accelerator.device) but now I'm trying to set a new device
model = RegressorModel(config, pooling='mean-pooling').to(device=device) #it istantiate a deberta-v3 model using AutoModel.from_pretrained()
```

Now I run the training and in the forward pass I do something like

```
def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
        outputs = self.model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask,
                               output_hidden_states=False) 
        print(outputs)
```

And it prints

```
BaseModelOutput(last_hidden_state=tensor([ ... ],
       device='cuda:0'), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)
```

So the device is not the one that I have set, how can I set the device correctly?